# Ios App Crashing After Launching with Archived App Built file from Xcode9.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am building/deploying an Ionic app in Xcode.

```
ionic ios build
```

Above command went well.

And built from `Xcode 9.2` and ran archive as well. I was been launching the app from archive file to iPhone. The app was opening, but it was crashing after it opens up.

**Cordova Plugins List**

```
cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release 1.1.4 "cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release"
cordova-plugin-admobpro 2.31.1 "AdMob Plugin Pro"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
cordova-plugin-extension 1.5.4 "Cordova Plugin Extension"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.4 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin"
cordova-plugin-file 4.3.3 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.3 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-filepath 1.0.2 "FilePath"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.1.1 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.4 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-stripe 1.5.3 "cordova-plugin-stripe"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

**Crash logs**

```
Incident Identifier: B5B0789F-48B9-4845-ACA8-43A90D105BDA
CrashReporter Key:   390906223b2bbe37cb9fee42cb41ec3f37ef09f6
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             MyHybridApp [3620]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E1DB741B-4662-4E7E-AF17-E9382E682B69/MyHybridApp.app/MyHybridApp
Identifier:          com.ionicframework.myhybridapp
Version:             1.4 (1.4)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.ionicframework.myhybridapp [1730]


Date/Time:           2018-02-09 15:49:29.3237 +0530
Launch Time:         2018-02-09 15:49:28.7265 +0530
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.2.5 (15D60)
Baseband Version:    4.30.02
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18121b164 __exceptionPreprocess + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x180464528 objc_exception_throw + 55
2   CoreFoundation                  0x18121b0ac +[NSException raise:format:] + 115
3   MyHybridApp                     0x104354ab0 0x104108000 + 2411184
4   MyHybridApp                     0x104354058 0x104108000 + 2408536
5   MyHybridApp                     0x104353d80 0x104108000 + 2407808
6   MyHybridApp                     0x10411da28 0x104108000 + 88616
7   UIKit                           0x18a8442c4 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 383
8   UIKit                           0x18aa35bc4 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3435
9   UIKit                           0x18aa3aa14 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1711
10  UIKit                           0x18acd62a8 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 799
11  UIKit                           0x18afae100 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 159
12  UIKit                           0x18acd5f0c -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 251
13  UIKit                           0x18acd676c -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 731
14  UIKit                           0x18b45b7c0 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 259
15  UIKit                           0x18b45b664 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 447
16  UIKit                           0x18b1c92cc __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 219
17  UIKit                           0x18b3623cc _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 111
18  UIKit                           0x18b1c917c -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 251
19  UIKit                           0x18afad760 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 363
20  UIKit                           0x18aa39158 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 539
21  UIKit                           0x18ae4edbc -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 363
22  FrontBoardServices              0x1838de1f0 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 363
23  FrontBoardServices              0x1838e6af8 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 223
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x180b9aa14 _dispatch_client_callout + 15
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x180ba2200 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 287
26  FrontBoardServices              0x1839127f8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 35
27  FrontBoardServices              0x18391249c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 403
28  FrontBoardServices              0x183912a38 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 55
29  CoreFoundation                  0x1811c377c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 23
30  CoreFoundation                  0x1811c36fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 87
31  CoreFoundation                  0x1811c2f84 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 203
32  CoreFoundation                  0x1811c0b5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1047
33  CoreFoundation                  0x1810e0c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 435
34  GraphicsServices                0x182f8cf84 GSEventRunModal + 99
35  UIKit                           0x18a8395c4 UIApplicationMain + 235
36  MyHybridApp                     0x10410ca08 0x104108000 + 18952
37  libdyld.dylib                   0x180c0056c start + 3


Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180d302e8 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e452f8 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000180c9efbc abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018043c068 __cxa_bad_cast + 0
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018043c210 default_unexpected_handler+ 8720 () + 0
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180464810 _objc_terminate+ 34832 () + 124
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018045454c std::__terminate(void (*)+ 107852 ()) + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001804545b8 std::terminate+ 107960 () + 60
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180b9aa28 _dispatch_client_callout + 36
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000180ba2200 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 288
10  FrontBoardServices              0x00000001839127f8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 36
11  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018391249c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 404
12  FrontBoardServices              0x0000000183912a38 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811c377c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811c36fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811c2f84 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811c0b5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1048
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001810e0c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
18  GraphicsServices                0x0000000182f8cf84 GSEventRunModal + 100
19  UIKit                           0x000000018a8395c4 UIApplicationMain + 236
20  MyHybridApp                     0x000000010410ca08 0x104108000 + 18952
21  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000180c0056c start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180d30d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e42eec _pthread_wqthread + 884
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e42b6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180d30d80 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e42eec _pthread_wqthread + 884
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e42b6c start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180d0f568 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180d0f3e0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811c3108 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001811c0cd4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1424
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001810e0c58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x0000000181b15594 -[NSRunLoop+ 50580 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x0000000181b349ac -[NSRunLoop+ 178604 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x000000018b3a37a8 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x0000000181c170f4 __NSThread__start__ + 996
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e442b4 _pthread_body + 308
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e44180 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e42b74 thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e42b68 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000180d300f0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e46ce4 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 640
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001803e7f34 std::__1::condition_variable::__do_timed_wait+ 32564 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >) + 96
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000188589168 std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable::wait_until<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >+ 10133864 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 124
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x000000018858903c std::__1::cv_status std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait_until<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>, std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >+ 10133564 (std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::steady_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > > const&) + 108
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x0000000188588ec0 bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>::threadRunLoop+ 10133184 () + 280
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001885891b8 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)(bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*), bmalloc::AsyncTask<bmalloc::Heap, void (bmalloc::Heap::*)()>*> >+ 10133944 (void*) + 44
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e442b4 _pthread_body + 308
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e44180 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000180e42b74 thread_start + 4
```

Can you please check with the error. I am using `xcode 9.2`  , `cordova-ios@4.1.0` , `ionic@2.2.3`

Comment: Have you tried your build from the browser?

Comment: yes , ionic serve was working fine

Comment: it was crashing from app build

Comment: Are you using any Cordova plugins that support on mobile devices only?

Comment: Yes Can I show you the list of plugins used , I will update in my question

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim updated plugins list in my question

Comment: Could you please try the build again in Xcode after excluding FCM plugin and all the related code? Let's first see how it goes.

Comment: I will try that and update you

Comment: this helped , thank you @JeffMinsungKim

Comment: I need to check adding fcm and recheck with the things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Let's assume that you've already set all the requirements of push notification correctly from your apple developer account page.*

If everything goes well after commenting out `FCM related code`, then I suppose your project probably missing `GoogleService-Info.plist` file. The .plist file doesn’t magically go to the right place properly in your iOS folder. *It goes in malformed*.

You’ll need to manually copy it from the project’s root folder to the Resources folder in Xcode. Also, this has to happen every time you remove and re-add your iOS app. Which is a very troublesome task to do. To solve this tedious issue, I do the following.

Since Cordova CLI 7.x.x, when using cordova-android 6.2.x or cordova-ios 4.4.x you can use the resource-file tag from config.xml.

For example,

```
<platform name="ios">
  <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
</platform>
```

It will include `GoogleService-Info.plist` file into the Resource folder during `ionic cordova build ios`.

I hope this helps you solve the crashing issue.

Comment: I will give a try on this once. Thank you for the answer

Comment: I have a question I didn't  get this file while configuring or adding fcm plugin into app . I have this file configuring from GooglePlus Sign In . Shall I add that file

Comment: You need `GoogleService-Info.plist` to use FCM. Do you use Firebase?

Comment: Yes I am using Firebase

Comment: You need to download the file and save it in the root directory of your project. That's all you need to do! Also, don't forget to enable `Push notification` in Capabilities tab on Xcode.

Comment: Thank you I will check with that

Comment: If your project works fine without having FCM plugin, then my answer should work. I had the same error message a few days ago.

Comment: I need FCM plugin which is a must

Comment: Yeah, I see your point. The only reason why I asked you to remove `FCM plugin` was to find out the primary cause.

Comment: I have came across the issue within the plugin repository issues . Following lines  solved my issue with FCM plugin

Comment: cp GoogleService-Info.plist platforms/ios/MyApp/Resources/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist
cp GoogleService-Info.plist platforms/ios/MyApp/Resources/GoogleService-Info.plist

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions and support @JeffMinsungKim

Comment: Accepting your answer

Comment: @Ranzit I'm glad I could help you :) Tips: You don't have to copy the `.plist` file using the command line. Including `resource-file tag` in config.xml will automatically copy the file for you during the build time.

Comment: Thank you Will try like that as well

Comment: do you have any idea on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859765/admob-pro-blank-boxwhite-box-ad-ios

Answer (score 0):

Check your GoogleService-Info.plist inside `platform/ios//resources` and inside `platform/ios//resources/resources`.
When build there is chance to corrupt please identify the corrupted one and change with right one

This help me save the time