# Admob Pro Blank Box(white box) Ad IOS

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, admob

I m using `Admob Pro` plugin for ios mobile app using `ionic`. 
I m getting a white box instead of Ad. There is no errors in the log
while showing the Ad.

Here is my code

```
this.admob.createBanner({
    adId: bannerId,
    adSize:'SMART_BANNER',
    height: 100,
    autoShow: false,
    isTesting: false 
    position: this.admob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER ,
})
return this.admob.showBanner(8);
```

Plugins used

```
cordova-plugin-admobpro 2.31.1 "AdMob Plugin Pro"
```

Please help me out

Comment: Also set `isTesting: false` to `isTesting: true`

Comment: Hey Ranzit, I've never used this plugin before. Maybe I should try using this plugin for my project in the future to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your banner id to test id:

> Banner: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111

or:

> Interstitial: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712